# Iterative solving of 2 equations results in "cannot determine truth value of Relational"

Tags: python, math, sympy

I am given these 2 equations with given values for a (alpha) and v.
I know that these cannot be solved classically but iteratively, so I want to use sympy and scipy to calculate phi (distribution).

My main goal is to calculate k1 and k2 (substituted with x and y in the code).

[image]

(I substitute k1 with x and k2 with y, alpha with a.)

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, exp
from scipy.stats import norm

x, y = symbols('x y')
v = 2.2526  # given
a = 0.1  # given

eq1 = (x + (1/v)) * exp((-(1/2)) * (x**2)) - (-y + (1/v)) * exp((-(1/2)) * (y**2))
eq2 = (((1 - norm.cdf(-1/v))**-1) * (norm.cdf(y) - norm.cdf(-x)) + a - 1)

sol = solve((eq1, eq2), (x, y))
print(sol)
```

If I run this I get

> TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")

What does this error mean?

Edit1:

```
x, y = symbols('x y', real=True)
```

leads to

> TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the
> inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
> the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: You have to use symbolic forms of all methods or they'll be evaluated by python. So `norm.cdf(y)` will be evaluated by scipy.stats.norm and will raise the exception because `y` is not a number. Try to write the CDF in symbolic form.

Comment: by symbolic form you mean something like this: CFDX=Symbol(norm.cdf(x))?

Comment: No, I mean an expression using only symbolic variables and [symbolic functions from sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/index.html) like the `sympy.exp` you are using.

Comment: seems like sympy has no phi (norm.cdf) calculation

Comment: No, but it does have the error function (erf) so you can construction a symbolic cdf expression yourself. I'll give it a try and see what I come up with.

Comment: SymPy's stats module can compute the cdf of a normal distribution although it's easy enough to do yourself with erf anyway.

Comment: you really should show the full error message.  But your use of the numeric `norm` is a good guess.  Did you test pieces of the problem line, like `norm.cdf(y)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your code and the hint provided by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74863253/iterative-solving-of-2-equations-results-in-cannot-determine-truth-value-of-rel#comment132120388_74863253), the following code can provide a numerical solution:

```py
from sympy import symbols, exp, nsolve, solve
from sympy.stats import Normal, cdf

x, y = symbols('x y')
T = Normal("t", 0, 1)
v = 2.2526  # given
a = 0.1  # given

eq1 = (x + (1 / v)) * exp((-(1 / 2)) * (x ** 2)) - (-y + (1 / v)) * exp((-(1 / 2)) * (y ** 2))
eq2 = (((1 - cdf(T)(-1 / v)) ** -1) * (cdf(T)(y) - cdf(T)(-x)) + a - 1)

sol = nsolve((eq1, eq2), (x, y), (1, 1))
# sol = solve((eq1, eq2), (x, y), (1, 1))
print(sol)

# output is: Matrix([[2.42082817559350], [0.284669014405097]])
```

The normally distributed continuous random variable with mean 0 and variance 1 is specified by `T = Normal("t", 0, 1)`, and the CDF is specified as `cdf(T)`. `nsolve` requires the caller to provide an estimate of the answer as for a starting point, so I guessed (1,1) and it worked.

Comment: Great answer.  I hope the OP accepts it.  Very insightful.

Answer (score 1):

Google found [this](https://groups.google.com/g/sympy/c/xmzoqW6tWaE).

This first answer suggests something to try:

> The problem is that the solver needs to know the sign of a certain expression in terms of the coefficients (the discriminant of a
> polynomial), and it cannot determine the sign based on the information
> given, as the discriminant ends up being `D = (1/(c2*r2) - 1/(c1*r1))**2`. Symbols are not automatically assumed real; so the
> square of some expression like that could even be negative. It's a
> good idea to declare symbols as real, by
>
> `python sym.symbols('i, r1, c1, r2, c2, t', real=True)`
>
> but this doesn't solve the problem because it might happen that c1*r1 == c2*r2, and then D is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The missing error message:

```
In [13]: from scipy.stats import norm

In [14]: eq2 = (((1 - norm.cdf(-1/v))**-1) * (norm.cdf(y) - norm.cdf(-x)) + a - 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [14], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 eq2 = (((1 - norm.cdf(-1/v))**-1) * (norm.cdf(y) - norm.cdf(-x)) + a - 1)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1955, in rv_continuous.cdf(self, x, *args, **kwds)
   1953 x = np.asarray((x - loc)/scale, dtype=dtyp)
   1954 cond0 = self._argcheck(*args) & (scale > 0)
-> 1955 cond1 = self._open_support_mask(x, *args) & (scale > 0)
   1956 cond2 = (x >= np.asarray(_b)) & cond0
   1957 cond = cond0 & cond1

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1000, in rv_generic._open_support_mask(self, x, *args)
    998 a, b = self._get_support(*args)
    999 with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
-> 1000     return (a < x) & (x < b)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py:511, in Relational.__bool__(self)
    510 def __bool__(self):
--> 511     raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Or using the `norm` by itself:

```
In [16]: norm.cdf(y)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

It's trying to test whether the argument `x` is within a certain range.  If `x` is a symbol that isn't a simple yes/no case.

Or narrowing it down even further, a symbolic relational, like `y<2` cannot be used in a context that expects a simple python True/False value.  With arrays we often see a `ambiguity` error; this is a symbolic equivalent:

```
In [22]: bool(y<2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [22], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 bool(y<2)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py:511, in Relational.__bool__(self)
    510 def __bool__(self):
--> 511     raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

In general, using sympy expressions and symbols in `numpy` and `scipy` does not work.  For limited cases involving addition and multiplication it's ok, but beyond that you'll like get errors.  Use `sympy's` own functions instead.